# Smallest Image of an endomorphism?

Tags: graph-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $\sigma = \{E\}$ be a signature with a binary relation symbol $E$ and let $\mathcal{G}$ be a $\sigma$-structure given by the following graph:

[image]

I'm wondering what the size of the smallest image of an endomorphism $g : \mathcal{G} \rightarrow_{hom} \mathcal{G}$ could be. My initial thought was "cutting" it in half i.e.
$$ g(v_0) := v_0 \quad g(v_1) := v_1 \quad g(v_2) := v_2 \quad g(v_3) := v_1 \quad g(v_4) := v_4 \quad g(v_5) := v_5 \quad g(v_6) := v_6 \quad g(v_7) := v_5 $$
until it resulted in
$$ g(v_0) := v_5 \quad g(v_1) := v_1 \quad g(v_2) := v_5 \quad g(v_3) := v_1 \quad g(v_4) := v_1 \quad g(v_5) := v_5 \quad g(v_6) := v_1 \quad g(v_7) := v_5 $$
Since I (guess I) can't project everything on one vertex the smallest image would be $|\{v_1, v_5\}| = 2$, right? Is it still an endomorphism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler way to see this is that $\mathcal G$ is bipartite as the subgraphs induced by $P_1 = \{v_1, v_3, v_4, v_6\}$ and $P_2 = \{v_0, v_2, v_5, v_7\}$ are independent sets and hence, the map $h$ defined as
$$h \colon \mathcal G \to \mathcal G, v \mapsto 
\begin{cases}
v_1, \text{ if } v \in P_1 \\
v_5, \text{ if } v \in P_2
\end{cases}
$$
is an endomorphism of $\mathcal G$ of minimal image size.

Comment: Where did I set $g(v_1) = g(v_5) = v_1$?

Comment: Oh sorry, seems like I misread when copying the drawing. In that case, your $g$ is the same as my $h$ after all.